# whats the right MIB OID to pull the mac addresses tables of the end user in hp Procurve switches?

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I have a script that can help to pull info from HP procurve by using the OID ...I need the right MIB OID to pull the mac addresses tables of the end user (the device Mac that connect to the port)

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- refer to the HP documentation on that matter or
- try to grep through [their MIBs](http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/) by mentions of MAC/link/L2 addresses or
- fire up `snmpwalk` over the whole OID space exposed by your device and search for MACs.

In the latter case, once you figure out the OID that have MACs as values, refer back to MIBs to make sure this is indeed the MIB object you are looking for.

Comment: still trying with the SNMP WALK ....still no luck ...thought might someone has the right OID

Answer (score -1):

Google "hp procurve snmp mac address table" gave me HP support articles about the question.

Comment: Please read the question .....I did google it of course ,,,all I'm asking if someone has the right OID or not ....that's it